# How to preview the type of selected expression in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Consider the following Java statement:

```
stringbuilder.append("some string");
```

Where `stringbuilder`is a `StringBuilder` object.

Is it possible to select the expression `stringbuilder.append("some string")` (without the `;`) and ask IntelliJ to what type this expression evaluates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Please look at the 
[InteliJ Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/evaluating-expressions.html)

Pay attention to "Evaluating arbitrary expressions" section.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I found it but the menu point is greyed out. Does this mean it is only available in the Ultimate Edition?

Comment: It should be available in Community Edition. You need to run your code in debug mode.